# Was the Italian 7th battalion, 11th division on the Austrian front in 1918?

Tags: identification, world-war-one, uniform, italian

The top image shows a postcard dated 7/10/1918, which was sent to my grandfather on the occasion of his 26th birthday.

He is 3rd from the left. I’m having difficulty making out what it says on the rear of the card addressed to ‘To Soldier Repetto … 14 … 7th Battalion 11th Division … War Zone’.

Can anyone confirm if this was the Austrian front? Was this an infantry division?

Any other information would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: 14th reggimento (abbreviato?) ?

Comment: 3rd Armata (Army) ? The 3rd was fighting up North vs the Austrian army, close to the border, at [Vittorio Veneto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Vittorio_Veneto)